# Selenium-side-runner not clearing input field before typing but works with Selenium Ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I'm trying to enter some text in `input` box so am using `type`. The input box has some default text and want to clear it before typing.

Normally, `type` in `Selenium Ide` should do the work as stated in [here](https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/selenium-ide/sendkeys-type).

This works well in `Selenium Ide` but when I save it and run the `.side` from `selenium-side-runner` it does not clear the text field. It just appends after it.

To work around this, I decided to use `send keys` with value `${KEY_SHIFT}${KEY_HOME}${KEY_SHIFT}${KEY_BACKSPACE}`. Again, this works as expected in `Selenium Ide` but when I run it from `selenium-side-runner` I get the following error:

```
info:    Running login.side
 FAIL  ./DefaultSuite.test.js
  Default Suite
   ✕ login (2775ms)

 ● Default Suite › login

 TypeError: each key must be a number of string; got undefined

  at forEach.key (../../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2011:15)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at WebElement.sendKeys (../../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2006:31)
```

Answer (score 1):

`send key` with`${KEY_SHIFT}${KEY_HOME}${KEY_SHIFT}${KEY_DELETE}` works.

`KEY_BKSP / KEY_BACKSPACE` doesn't seem to work.

Had to do hit and try to get the solution. Theres no documentation either as of now showing supported keys.

Comment: Great solution and more stable than the command "type" with an empty string, because some applications do some stuff after a key is pressed in an input field. Imho the command "type" doesn't raise such an event and so the test could be unstable. That's my lessons learned testing a modern Angular application.